# Prove that in finite steps you can know if the solution set of linear programming problem is unbounded

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, proof-writing, linear-programming, operations-research

Given is $\max\left\{c^T \cdot x | Ax \leq b, x \geq 0\right\}$ which is a linear programming problem and its solution set $M$. Prove that you can find out in finite steps if $M$ is unbounded.

---

It will surely work using the Simplex algorithm but I'm not sure how to prove this correctly?

I think the same proof to this is: Prove that the Simplex algorithm will stop (in finite steps). It will stop in finite steps because there are finite number of feasible bases. In addition, every feasible basis determines a basic feasible solution with an objective value. To make sure that a feasible basis is never used more than once, one can strictly increase the objective value in every step. For this reason, the Simplex algorithm will come to an end in finite steps.

But I'm not sure if this is fine like that or if it's really a proof at all? :S

Comment: In simplex you need an anti-cycling rule, but just enumerating all possible basis vectors will work, using revised simplex to check for a direction of recession.

Comment: @LinAlg I'm not sure if what I've written counts as a proof. Do you know? :)

Comment: it doesn't, since you cannot expect to strictly increase the objective value in every step of the simplex method

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thank you I didn't see that :D But your answer there, is that really a proof? Because here the problem is proving it and your answer and also the question look more like a reason (how do we know that the Simplex method will provide us a solution that is unbounded / bounded in finite steps?). Or I misunderstand something and that is not necessary to show?

Comment: with anti cycling rule, simplex algorithm terminates in finite number of steps.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh But this is not necessary to be proven here?

Comment: the result that simplex with anti cycling rule terminates is a standard result. say for example, [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/407/notes/section3.pdf). The challenge of this question is to think of  using simplex method on which optimization problem.